# Array of images stacked next to each other, using LayerDrawable.(Displaying multiple image in single imageview)

Tags: android, android-drawable, layerdrawable

I have 5 images, I need to display this horizontally spaced one after the other. Instead of using 5 different images to display these 5 images in a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation, I would like to use a single image view. With LayerDrawable can I achieve this? If yes how?

All I want is to place images like in the sample below, where each of 'Querstions', 'Tags', 'Users', 'Badges', 'Unanswered' would be an image.

[image]

Comment: http://myandroidtipsandtricks.blogspot.in/2012/09/drawables-part-ii.html

Comment: @AM , In my case all the images are of same size. Can I still achieve what I need ?

Comment: In my I have list view, rows of list view has to show 1 to 5 images next to each other based on a condition. Having 1 to 5 imageview is hitting scroll performance

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#Summary .... try this may be it'll help you

Comment: If you'll try horizontal scroll view in this list ... this is a good way ... I suppose ... if you need the click of that 5 images

Comment: no, I dont need to listen to click events

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41194/discussion-between-a-m-and-jeez)

Comment: thanks for the pointers, I got it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, this is how I did

each image is of dimension 48*48. I start at left edge of imageivew hence l value for 1st layer is l = 0 and r = 52, because am providing 4 units padding and image width is 48 units  (48+4 = 52), then for second image I use l = 52 (starts where 1st layer ends) and again r = 52 . If there is a third image of dimension 48*48 then l and r value for third layer would be l = 104 r = 52 and so on

activity-class

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layer_list_main);
        LayerDrawable drw = createHorizontallyStackedImages();
        ImageView iv1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        iv1.setImageDrawable(drw);

    }

     private LayerDrawable createHorizontallyStackedImages(){  
         BitmapDrawable d1 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abcgo_48_48_2x);  
         d1.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);  
         BitmapDrawable d2 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.amazon_48x48_2x);  
         d2.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);  
         //BitmapDrawable d3 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hulu_48x48_2x);  
         //d3.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);  

         Drawable drawableArray[]= new Drawable[]{d1,d2};  
         LayerDrawable layerDraw = new LayerDrawable(drawableArray);  
         layerDraw.setLayerInset(0, 0, 0, 52, 0);
         layerDraw.setLayerInset(1,52,0,52,0);

         return layerDraw;  
       }
```

activity-xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".LayerListMainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

result looks as below

[image]

With this approach, we can merge several images into single LayerDrawable and display the resulting merged image in singel imageview

Comment: Can we extend above method for 2D array of images? Any suggestions/documents for both the possibilties.