# Multiple images single view mispositioned Android

Tags: android, android-drawable, layerdrawable

I am following the answer given here [Array of images stacked next to each other, using LayerDrawable.(Displaying multiple image in single imageview)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978985/array-of-images-stacked-next-to-each-other-using-layerdrawable-displaying-mult)
. My images are 38x38 sized.

This is my code:

```
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
layers[0]=cActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.white_pawn);
layers[1]=cActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_pawn);

LayerDrawable pawns = new LayerDrawable(layers);
pawns.setLayerInset(0, 0, 0, 42, 0);
pawns.setLayerInset(1, 42, 0, 42, 0);
((ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.baseImage)).setImageDrawable(pawns);
```

But that's what happens: [layers misplaced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38r9i.png)

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference with the question you are referring is that you are not setting the gravity for drawables. IIRC Drawables by default try to fill the the layer.

```
    layers[0].setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    layers[1].setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
```

Comment: Ok, you are right, just tried, it works, ty! The thing's that the method setGravity is not available for Drawables, that's why I was forced to use BitMap Drawable, which I wanted to avoid simply because it seem to work without it. But you are right, ty very much sir!